# I want to learn javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to learn javascript soon and I would like to ask for your opinion about the online sites where I could start: Udemy, Pluralsight, Codecademy ... 
Which one is better? I attended a training in Angular on Pluralsight and I can say that I like it but I would like to try something new if it is worth it.

Comment: Please read the FAQ regarding what kinds of questions to ask on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used PluralSight and I can say it was worth it. In my opinion, it only matters when you think you will succeed in learning. I recommend Udemy because you can purchase a Javascript course that you will have at your disposal all your life. 
If you use Pluralsight you have to pay a monthly fee, but you have access to all the courses.